# javascript issue, argument name not showing proper value

Tags: javascript

hope you can clarify this issue:

Bassically i am following a tutorial for javascript, the man on the tutorial is writing this code and getting the result: hi James;
what i get is: hi ${name};

```
   function greet(name){
        console.log('hi ${name}');
    }
    greet('James');ter code here
```

when I use the code like it:

```
function greet(name){
    console.log('hi' +' '+ name);
}
greet('James');
greet('John');
greet('kate');
```

it works and shows the corect result with all of them, does anyone can explain why I can not get the result using console.log('hi ${name}');.

thank you so much in advance, also if somene would like to recomend any tutorial for the basics of javascript it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Its actually a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that are enclosed by the backtick ``` (``) ``` (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes.

```js
function greet(name) {
  console.log(`hi ${name}`);
}
greet('James');
```